# Failed contract execution in function swap()

Tags: remix, solidity-0.8.x

I am using sepolia test network and have 0.621 SepoliaETH in Metamask.
This is my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "./Token.sol";
contract Swap {
    address private tokenAddress;
    address private owner;
    Token private token;

    event UnexpectedTransaction(address sender, uint256 value);
    event AssetSold(address sender, uint256 amount);
    event AssetBought(address sender, uint256 amount);
    event LogMessage(string message);
    event LogMessages(string message, string message2);
    event LogCustom(address message, uint256 message2);
    event EtherReceived(address sender, uint256 amount);

    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
        logExample();
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    function swap(address _tokenAddress, address _fromAddress, address _toAddress) public payable{
        //fuel
        emit LogMessage("Begin fuel");
        uint256 _swapAmount = address(this).balance;
        emit LogMessage(string(abi.encodePacked("Swap amount: ", uint256ToString(_swapAmount))));
        emit LogMessage("Fuel...");

        require(_swapAmount > 0 , "You have to at least deposit something to start a DEX");
        token = Token(address(_tokenAddress));
        //buy
        uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(_swapAmount <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
        token.transfer(_fromAddress, _swapAmount);
        emit AssetBought(_fromAddress, _swapAmount);
        //sell
        uint256 approvedAmt = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(approvedAmt >= _swapAmount, "Check the token allowance");
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _swapAmount);
        payable(_toAddress).transfer(_swapAmount);
        emit AssetSold(msg.sender, _swapAmount);
    }

    function logExample() public payable{
        emit LogMessages(addressToString(msg.sender), uint256ToString(msg.value));
        emit LogCustom(msg.sender, msg.value);
        emit LogMessage("Hola mundo!");
    }

    receive() external payable {
        // Code to handle the received Ether
        emit LogMessage("EtherReceived"); //<-- not visible in logs
        emit EtherReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        emit UnexpectedTransaction(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

   
    function getRemainingGas() public view returns (uint256) {
        return gasleft();
    }
}
```

The deployment succeeds: [https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x275f269edb42b182e5aa342e3a3843a211c18cd6971815eec9ec06d40f46f4e2#eventlog](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x5849c354e40dc91e82fb074f5cd3f9d5493e8f48ca12b3e42f3895f00cdb5c45)

But "EtherReceived" not visible in logs.

Then execution fails when using the function swap(): https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x5849c354e40dc91e82fb074f5cd3f9d5493e8f48ca12b3e42f3895f00cdb5c45

The function getRemainingGas() appears to work and returns **0: uint256: 2978818**

Any clue what is wrong with my contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EtherReceived:

`receive()` will only be called when the contract accepts transfer of ether from others and msg.data is empty.

### swap():

I debugged your contract in remix, there is no problem with swap().

1. Make sure the swp contract holds ether.
2. You should ensure that the contract holds a sufficient amount of tokens or more than the Wei ether held by your contract (`uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));`).
3. Before executing `token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _swapAmount);`, you need to call the Token contract first, and authorize enough tokens of msg.sender to the Swp contract.